# Is there a way to "morph" one word into another in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have set up a basic clock that runs off of the system time. I have all of that working, but I was trying to add an animation to the numbers so that whenever they changed, it wasn't just instant. I was able to make it transition by fading out, then fading in with the new number, but that is not exactly what I want. I want the text to always be visible, and fade into another text. Not from text to white, then from white to new text.

```js
var hours, minutes, seconds, date;
function updateClock() {
    if (hours < 10) {
        hours = parseInt(hours);
        hours = "0" + hours;
    };

    if (minutes < 10) {
        minutes = parseInt(minutes);
        minutes = "0" + minutes;
    };

    if (seconds < 10) {
        seconds = parseInt(seconds);
        seconds = "0" + seconds;
    };

    $("#clock").text(hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds);
};
function getTime() {
    date = new Date;
    hours = date.getHours();
    minutes = date.getMinutes();
    seconds = date.getSeconds();
    updateClock();
};

getTime();
setInterval(getTime, 1000);
```

```css
#clock {
    position: absolute;
    width: 500px;
    height: 175px;
    left: calc(50% - 250px);
    top: calc(50% - 87.5px);
    background-color: lightgray;
    color: black;
    font-size: 125px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="clock"></div>
```

Comment: is this still an open question? it seems like it didn't receive any attention as it is over a year old. Also I don't see any white text trying to fade out and in. Can you please elaborate